# css fill spaces left by missing content

Tags: css

i have this situation where dynamic content does not fill up correctly in the designated area, so I need to fill it so that it can fit correctly.

I made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/yvK2h/1/ so that you can see what i want to make. I want paragraph 3 to go under paragraph 1 and fill the space underneath paragraph 1.

css:

```
.row {width:50%; float:left;}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">1. </div>
<div class="row">2. </div>
<div class="row">3. </div>
<div class="row">4. </div>
```

Is that possible without javascript only using css?

**Update:**

Please consider I cannot add columns since i might have 4 or 7 columns, and not necessarily in the same order. For example column 4 might be under col 1 if col 3 is hidden.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yhS4u/

Comment: @farmerjoe - but you totally changed the HTML.

Comment: @Danko - is there any way you can make it with javascript or so?

Comment: There are several JavaScript solutions out there, for example http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: is that what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/yvK2h/4/

Comment: Noted, I shall reattempt.

Comment: @mugur like j08691 says are multiple JS solutions check the masonry is a good one

Comment: @San no. i need to keep the 2 cols together and fill the space under col 1 with col 3 so that col 3 will be right under col 1.

Comment: Oh sorry, then try masonry or isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

Comment: @j08691 - i got it finally working with masonry. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/yvK2h/4/

```
.row {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
.row {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    margin:0 0 30px 0
}
}
```